# HTML/CSS renderizado de manera extraña

Tags: html, css, less

Tengo un problema con el renderizado HTML/CSS.

Cómo es posible que de éste código:

```
<div class="gal-preview">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="link-thumbnail">
            <img src="img/submissions/01/over_the_hedge.jpg">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="title">The hedge must be jumped!</div>
                <a>AAAA</a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Me renderice esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es introducir el link AAAA que tengo de prueba, y todo se descuadra de manera anormal.

El CSS es el siguiente:

```
.gal {
    padding: 5px;
    .gal-preview {
        width: 20%;
        height: 15vw;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        .thumbnail {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #6a6a6a;
            a.link-thumbnail {
                .position(absolute, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                    max-height: 100%;
                    .position(absolute, 50%, initial, initial, 50%);
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }
                .info {
                    padding: 10px;
                    .position(absolute, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    .title {
                        text-overflow: ellipsis;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        white-space: nowrap;
                        color: #f0f0f0;
                    }
                    .author {
                        .position(absolute, initial, 10px, 10px, 10px);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &::after {
        .afterClear;
    }
}
.position(@position, @top: initial, @right: initial, @bottom: initial, @left: initial) {
    position: @position;
    top: @top;
    right: @right;
    bottom: @bottom;
    left: @left;
}
.afterClear {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Añado JSFIDDLE con únicamente la primera celda de prueba con este código: https://jsfiddle.net/vo3d6zk9/

El objetivo de tener un `a` dentro del otro, es que si hago clic en toda la celda, exceptuando el `AAAA` que sería otro enlace, me llevara al detalle de esa imagen. No tengo problemas en colocar el enlace `AAAA` fuera, pero me ha dejado atónito y quiero saber básicamente porque rederiza de esta manera.

Comment: Por lo visto es eso, un `<a>` dentro de otro `<a>` provoca ese desorden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un `a` dentro de otro es inválido en html y no hay una descripción formal de cómo manejar ese caso, por lo que cada motor lo hace a su manera y el resultado es relativamente impredecible.

Por cierto, si se diera el caso de que el DOM se estructure como lo planteas, al hacer click en el `a` de adentro el evento se propagaría por el árbol y también generaría un click en el `a` exterior.

La mejor forma de hacer lo que quieres es reemplazar el `a` de adentro por otro elemento, y detectar el click directo con JavaScript, frenar la propagación con `event.stopPropagation()` y luego ejecutar la acción deseada.

Comment: Ok, merci por la aclaración, ese detalle no lo conocía. Bueno, lo he conseguido hacer colocando el enlace interior fuera. Aunque pensaba que no lo haría, y que el click sería como en jQuery, el clicado aunque tuviera padre, haría caso al hijo.